# Store a list of objects in db4o

Tags: java, db4o

I wonder if there's a more beautiful way to store a list of objects then:

```
ArrayList<Item> itemsList = new ArrayList<Item>;
itemsList.add(new Item(1));
itemsList.add(new Item(2));

ItemDBProvider dbProvider = new ItemDBProvider();

for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++){
    dbProvider.store(itemsList.get(i));
}

dbProvider.getDB().commit();
dbProvider.close();
```

Note, ItemDBProvider is just a wrapper for extended class which opens and uses ObjectContainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the enhanced for loop (Java 1.5+):

```
for (Item item:itemsList) {
    dbProvider.store(item);
}
```

Comment: That's more elegantly, thank you! But I was wondering if there is a special db4o method for storing typed array or list...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `objectcontainer.store(itemsList)` to store the whole list together with its elements.

The DB does not know that this is a list of `Item`, though - as Java's generic types are only available in compile-time. It would just as well store an `List<Object>` with these items in it.

Comment: I am trying to do this, just store the list into my ObjectContainer. It works fine as long as the server is running, but stopping it and restarting it will clear the lists. Would you have any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: @Alex: I have no idea here. You might want to create a minimal reproducing example and post it either here as a new question, or in the db4o forums.

Comment: Ye thanks, I did that the other day and got the answer that it was an issue with the UpdateDepth... so I increased it and now it all works. :)